# function to read multiple fcs indexed file and store them into a dataframe

Tags: r, function

I am a beginner R user
I have multiple index FACS sorting files (.fcs) and I want to create a function that reads all the files (using the FlowCore package) but I always run into some errors I don't understand

here is what my code looks like, and the error I get:

```
fcs_to_dataframe<-function(fcs){
  name<-tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(fcs))
  fcs_data<-read.FCS(fcs, header=TRUE)
  fcs_data<-data.frame(getIndexSort(fcs_data))
  write.csv(fcs_data, paste0("/", name ,".csv"))
}
lapply(all.fcs, fcs_to_dataframe)
```

Erreur dans file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
impossible d'ouvrir la connexion
De plus : Message d'avis :
Dans file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
Erreur dans file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
impossible d'ouvrir la connexion

anyone has an idea on how to fix my issue? thanx!

Comment: You are unable to open the connection - that means the file does not exist. After the line, `name<-tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(fcs))`, can you add `print(name)` and see what it outputs? Also run `getwd()` and make sure you are in the directory you think you are.

Comment: @SamR I don't thinks it's the issue, if I add the print(name) I do get the name of the first file in the folder and then the same error as earlier.
 If I remove the other lines 
`fcs_data<-read.FCS(fcs, header=TRUE)
  fcs_data<-data.frame(getIndexSort(fcs_data))
  write.csv(fcs_data, paste0("/", name ,".csv"))`
I do get a list f al the names of my files in the folder, so I think the issue may be about how I name my variables fcs_data ?

Comment: Non, le problème n'est pas le nom de la variable. The error is that you cannot open the connection, meaning it is either reading the file or writing the file. If you comment out `write.csv(fcs_data, paste0("/", name ,".csv"))` does the code run? That should give you an indication of whether the problem is reading or writing.

Comment: If I comment out the writing part I get: Erreur dans cbind(exprs(x), locs) : 
le nombre de lignes des matrices doit correspondre (voir argument 2)

Comment: OK we are getting somewhere I think. The fact that there was not an error with `cbind` the first time you ran it, but there is a second time, means that you have managed to run at least the first file successfully. Which you were unable to do before. This means that the error in your original question was that you were unable to _write_ the csv.  I think if you change that line to `write.csv(fcs_data, paste0("./", name ,".csv"))` it should solve that problem (note the .). As for this new problem, it is hard to say without seeing the data why it is occuring!

Comment: if I add the "./" as you ask i get the same error Erreur dans cbind(exprs(x), locs) : 
le nombre de lignes des matrices doit correspondre (voir argument 2)

Comment: @SamR okay so the same error is still there, but all the files have been written correctly so I don't know what to make of it but thank you